# Rename images in folders with ground truth .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `images` folder, inside the images folder, it contains 150 folders and each folder contains 10,000 images. The single `gt.txt` is outside the `images` folder and contains all images' names with ground truth values.

The structure of `gt.txt` is like `images/0/0.jpg   참자녀사무실`.

I would like to rename all images with patterns like `gt_image_name.jpg` like `참자녀사무실_0.jpg`. However, I am unable to do so, I wrote a simple code but I think the glob library doesn't work on the folder.

**Code**

```
mapping = {}
f = open('/media/cvpr/CM_22/synthtiger/results/gt.txt', 'r')

for line in f.readlines():
    k, v = line.split()
    path, old_name = k.rsplit('/', 1)
    new_name = "{}/{}_{}".format(path, v, old_name)
    mapping[k] = v

base_path = '/media/cvpr/CM_22/synthtiger/results/'
for old, new in mapping.items():
    old_path = os.path.join(base_path, old)
    new_path = os.path.join(base_path, new)
    os.rename(old_path, new_path)
```

**Incorrect Output**

[image]

Comment: I have cleared all the things, why the question has been closed?

Comment: "I would like to rename all images with gt_image_name.jpg like 참자녀사무실_0.jpg" What is the rule that tells you the new filename?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It's just taking `images/0/0.jpg   참자녀사무실` and changing the file named `0.jpg` to `참자녀사무실_0.jpg`

Comment: Okay, but **why** is `참자녀사무실_0.jpg` the correct new name? How do I know what the new name should be? Will we always add `참자녀사무실_` in front? Does it depend on the `0` value? Some other rule?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel We were told in the question that every line in the text document follows that pattern. If the next line was `images/0/whatever.jpg   just` the new name for the file would be `just_whatever.jpg`

[This demonstrates how the pattern matching works with a completely different set of text.](https://onecompiler.com/python/3ykm3eym4)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do like this:

1. read the gt.txt, read the file, use `split` get raw name `raw_name` and the part of real name `img_name`;
2. use `{}_{}.format(img_name, raw_name)` to compose a new filename;
3. use a `for` loop to rename all image, you can use `os.rename` to do this.

update:
my experience is that not use any loop more than two layers

```
mapping = {}
f = open('/media/cvpr/CM_22/synthtiger/results/gt.txt', 'r'):
for line in f.readlines():
    k, v = line.split(' ')
    path, old_name = k.rsplit('/', 1)
    new_name = "{}/{}_{}".format(path, v, old_name)
    mapping[k] = v
base_path = '/media/cvpr/CM_22/synthtiger/results/images/'
for old, new in mapping.items():
    old_path = os.path.join(base_path, old)
    new_path = os.path.join(base_path, new)
    os.rename(old_path, new_path)
```

now, you have a dict save like `{"images/0/0.jpg": "images/0/참자녀사무실_0.jpg"}`
after that, use a another `for` loop to rename all files

note:multiple circle is bad code habit, because its hard to debug, and hard to read, easy make mistake, finally no one understand your code,include yourself.
update: use loop like this,no need to list all file, just use mapping to rename filename

Comment: Could you please mention some code sample? I have also updated my code

Comment: Why not use an f-string? `new_name = f"{path}/{v}_{old_name}"`

Comment: @shawn-caza you can use any you like method, why not not use f-string?this not the question point.

Comment: Certainly, but if we're talking about 'hard to read', is the f-string easier to read? Is there any downside?

Comment: @shawn-caza I mean multiple circle is hard to read. f-string or not f-string is not the point of 'hard to read', and, the f-string not the single choice.stop this boring argument, please focus on answer this question.

Comment: @Auraxc when i am retrieving all folder it is  not sorted i tried sorted method but it didnt work. any idea?

Comment: @khawar-islam not need sorted them, use mapping to rename them.

Comment: @Auraxc after saving ht name of image is wrong, i need to be in this order 참자녀사무실_0.jpg but now we have like 참자녀사무실

Comment: @khawar-islam you can print the mapping to check which code is wrong, I give you a example to do this,maybe you need fix some detail

Comment: @Auraxc I am trying to fix but i do not have image name that is the problem.

Comment: try to print old_path and new_path, check what wrong in path @khawar-islam

Comment: maybe because the `\n`, replace `k, v = line.split(' ')` by `k, v = line.replace('\n', '').split(' ')`

Comment: @KhawarIslam I'm not sure what exactly is going wrong with the first for loop in this answer, but I [re-wrote it here](https://onecompiler.com/python/3ykm3eym4) and it seems to work as expected. Since the question is closed I can't add the code here as an answer.

Comment: It's that `mapping[k] = v` should be changed to `mapping[k]=new_name`